# apt-cacher-ng docker configuration problem

Tags: docker, shell, terminal, apt, synology

I'm trying to set up a docker for my Synology NAS so I can use the apt command in my server shell.

I've followed every single tutorial here and some more:
[https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-apt-cacher-ng\](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-apt-cacher-ng%5C)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlbN5kWbzVE

It seems like a pretty simple tutorial, but I'm stuck at the end.

The docker installation and configuration seem to be ok because I can see the docker website with the final instructions to add the proxy, but from there to the end something is not working.

Next steps:

1. All the tutorial sais i have to create a file or add a line to the file "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptproxy" if already exists.
2. Then edit the file and add the proxy : Acquire::http::Proxy "http://main_server_ip:3142";
3. After that all the tutorials show that suddenly you can call "apt update" on the main shell and it's working.

My problem is in step 1 I don't even have the apt folder on /etc and even if I create all the folders, the file and add the Proxy line, the step 3 say apt: command not found

Anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: The `apt` command is only available on Debian linux and derivatives like Ubuntu, etc.., and those are the operating systems meant to be used with `apt-cacher-ng`. On the computer that's telling you `apt: command not found`... what output do you get when running the `uname -a` command?